# Can't make a connection to remote MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I tried to connect to my database with mysqli_connect. this database is a remote MySQL database but my code gives the following error:

> Warning: Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=94 in ~\dashboard\config_app.php on line 16

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in ~\dashboard\config_app.php on line 16
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=14572 in ~\dashboard\config_app.php on line 16

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in ~\dashboard\config_app.php on line 16
> ERROR: Could not connect. MySQL server has gone away

The code:

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER_app', 'server host name');
define('DB_USERNAME_app', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD_app', 'password');
define('DB_NAME_app', 'database name');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link_app = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER_app, DB_USERNAME_app, DB_PASSWORD_app, DB_NAME_app);

?>
```

I'm sure the credentials aren't the problem.
Someone how knows what the problem is?

Comment: FYI:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based admin gui written in PHP for managing MySQL databases. Your application talks to MySQL directly and has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Check if the server name (host) is correct, that it uses the default port (3306, if not, you need to define the port in your connection) and that the mysql server and the database user allows remote connections.